# Magento 2 Store switcher error in "section-config.js" Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '*' of undefined(…)

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, blocks, javascript, store-switcher

I'm implementing a custom store switcher in my custom theme.

Block template is as follow:

```
<?php if (count($block->getStores())>1): ?>
    <?php $id = $block->getIdModifier() ? '-' . $block->getIdModifier() : ''?>

    <span><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getStoreName()) ?></span>

    <span>/</span>

    <?php foreach ($block->getStores() as $_lang): ?>
        <?php if ($_lang->getId() != $block->getCurrentStoreId()): ?>
            <span class="view-<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_lang->getCode()); ?> switcher-option">
                <a href="#" data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getTargetStorePostData($_lang); ?>'>
                    <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_lang->getName()) ?>
                </a>
            </span>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

The link to new store is correctly displayed so I guess the xml stuff is OK, but on click I receive the following error:

> section-config.js:33 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '*' of
>   undefined(…)

The generated `html` looks like the following:

```
<span class="view-it switcher-option">
  <a href="#" data-post="{"action":"http:\/\/test.mysite.eu\/stores\/store\/switch\/","data":{"___store":"it","uenc":"aHR0cDovL3Rlc3QuZnJhZ2lhY29tb21pbGFuby5ldS8,"}}">
    It
  </a>
</span>
```

Comment: Have you run deploy command and remove var folder?

Comment: nope XD I'll do it and follow up

Comment: I just ran `sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` w/o any luck. Why shall I remove `var` folder? What exactly should I remove?

Comment: you have to remove all content of var folder

Comment: works for you or not?

Comment: it's still deleting everything ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49358/discussion-between-davideghz-and-rakesh).

Comment: I get the same error

Comment: @davideghz did you get the solution ?

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem and found out that these two blocks where not called any more due to customizations in the theme.

The two blocks are per default added in the `<referenceContainer name="content">` of vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/layout/default.xml.

Try re-adding these blocks in your layout.xml:

```
<block name="customer.section.config" class="Magento\Customer\Block\SectionConfig"
    template="Magento_Customer::js/section-config.phtml"/>
<block name="customer.customer.data"
    class="Magento\Customer\Block\CustomerData"
    template="Magento_Customer::js/customer-data.phtml"/>
```

Comment: I have the same Problem but the Blocks are rendered. I guess it's because I am in a requireJs method while calling the cart reload method, but the JS is executed before the block is rendered. Can I depend on any js module to avoid this?

Comment: Just had this exact same problem.. while using https://github.com/SnowdogApps/magento2-theme-blank-sass (Magento 2.2.6). Adding the two above blocks fixed the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

On our project we fixed it in the `section-config.js` file in the method `getAffectedSections` (which is where our error was).
We replaced the last line:

```
return _.union(_.toArray(actions), _.toArray(sections['*']));
```

By the following one:

```
return (sections && sections.length > 0) ? _.union(_.toArray(actions), _.toArray(sections['*'])) : {};
```

To actually returns an empty array when no section is affected.

Comment: Does your solution work well?

Comment: Yes it was a functionning workaround, but IIRC, the real root of our issue was a slight misuse of the JS API in the end. It did not make this fix unrelevant, it's still a protection to ensures the code keeps running and does not stop here, in not critical error cases.

Comment: Thanks, It's working..

Comment: It is working for me also. But in some categories when I change store view, after store view is changed I get invalid form key. Please refresh page. No form is there though....I am confused

Comment: Working fine :) thanks you very much.

Comment: @Flinth May you please share what was the cause of the issue and how did you debug it?

Answer (score 0):

Ran across the same issue even though the `customer.section.config` and `customer.customer.data` were properly loaded into the page.

In my case however it happened because an extension tried to trigger a section-reload too early (before section-config.js was loaded with the right configuration).

Managed to solve it by adding a breakpoint in `getAffectedSections` of section-config.js and checking the url variable. Then moved the extension JS to load after the customer.section.config block:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="extension.js.block" destination="content" after="customer.section.config"/> 
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

In our case this was a bit of code in a default template which was loading the customer-data.js file after it had already been called on the success page.

We found file: `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/success.phtml`

was loading this code:

```
<script>
    require([
        'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
    ], function (customerData) {
        var sections = ['cart'];
        customerData.invalidate(sections);
        customerData.reload(sections, true);
    });
</script>
```

Removing this code fixed it, which we did by creating a copy of this file in our theme templates directory and removing the offending code snippet.

You can use Chrome Dev tools to find out where the error was happening and then just before in that file on your local dev add in a `console.trace();` call to establish what was calling the function which is throwing the error in the console. Follow the chain to where you are loading things improperly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, someone has removed the "columns" container like below from the custom page layout

```
<referenceContainer name="columns" remove="true" />
```

Removing this line makes it working and the error is gone.