# Magento 2: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '*' of undefined in (section-config.js:33)

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, javascript, addtocart

It's [duplicate question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148170/magento2-store-switcher-error-in-section-config-js-uncaught-typeerror-canno) but I am facing the same issue while adding the product & removing items from the cart page.

I have spent almost a day to resolve but no luck hope someone could help me with this.

Error Message in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '*' of undefined in (section-config.js:33)

**Edit: I have run the deploy & deleted all the cache still issue persist.**

Comment: See my answer here https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/186636/231

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento2 - Store switcher error in "section-config.js" Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '\*' of undefined(…)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148170/magento2-store-switcher-error-in-section-config-js-uncaught-typeerror-canno)

Comment: Make sure you're not removing the content referenceContainer in any of your layouts `<referenceContainer name="content" display="false"/>`

Comment: The solution is already provided in https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148170/magento-2-store-switcher-error-in-section-config-js-uncaught-typeerror-cannot/186636#186636
Refer the above.

Comment: please apply magento normal command like : upgrade,deploy etc.

Comment: sometimes you need to wait until the page load

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and found my way to this page several times.

I ran into this when a custom module links js in the html head from an xml layout and `dev/js/enable_js_bundling` + `dev/js/minify_files` are both set to **1**, with JS deferred to the bottom of the page (either with a 3rd party plugin or dev/js/move_script_to_bottom as of 2.3.2).